# How can I display an image that is stored on a remote server in a hbs page? Is that even possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Here's the piece of code that I'm talking about. That imglink variable is the link to the image on a remote server. The link is coming alright and when I load this page with the default .html extension, it works fine. But the problem comes when I'm using hbs

```
<img src="{{imglink}}" alt="Image not Found" style="border-radius: 5px;" height="300px" width="250px">
```

Here's the part where I render the data I fetched:-

```
res.render("Found.hbs",{
   imglink: link,
   title: title,
   pages: pages,
   artist: authors
});
```

And here's the compiled output of the code:-

```
<img src="https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/635/1.jpg" alt="Image not Found" style="border-radius: 5px;" height="300px" width="250px">
```

It works fine when I use the .html extension. The **only** time it doesn't work is when I am using the .hbs extension. Even if I hardcode the link, the image is not loading in the **.hbs** extension.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please [edit] your question to tell us what's going wrong. And remember, View Source ... in the browser shows you the rendered page. Your `{{imglink}}` operation may be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @O.Jones The rendered page is coming just fine. The image is loading when I am changing the extension to .html. The only time it's not loading is when I am using .hbs extension

Comment: It's generally incorrect to say `res.render('file.hbs', ...)`. Instead you want to say ` `res.render('file', ...)` in your code. Express supplies the `.hbs` part. [Read this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars).

Comment: could you try it removing the https part?

Comment: @O.Jones I removed the .hbs extension in res.render but I am still getting the same result

Comment: @HossamMaher Yup. No good